# How to download object from AWS S3 into memory and send it via request in Go?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, go-gin

Can someone please help me solve this error I got while trying to download a file from S3.

So I want to create storage service api via Go Gin, and I want a route where it take S3 object key to download the object then send this object back to client.

```
cfg,_ := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO())

// Create an Amazon S3 service client
s3Client := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)
downloader := manager.NewDownloader(s3Client)
```

```
    router.POST("/download-s3", func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        var data map[string]string

        if err := ctx.ShouldBindJSON(&data); err != nil {
            log.Println("Error: bind error")
            ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
            return
        }

        log.Println("Body Request data (fileKey): ", data["fileKey"])

        fileKey := data["fileKey"]

        /// Buffer read
        buf := make([]byte, 100)
        // wrap with aws.WriteAtBuffer
        w := manager.NewWriteAtBuffer(buf)
        // download file into the memory
        numBytesDownloaded, err := downloader.Download(ctx, w, &s3.GetObjectInput{
            Bucket: aws.String(bucketName),
            Key:    aws.String(fileKey),
        })
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Error: download error")
            ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
            return
        }

        ctx.JSON(http.StatusAccepted,
            gin.H{
                "message":            fmt.Sprintf("'%s' downloaded!", "test.jpg"),
                "numBytesDownloaded": numBytesDownloaded,
            },
        )

        ctx.Data(http.StatusOK, "application/octet-stream", w.Bytes())

    })
```

This above code gave me this error of :
`operation error S3: GetObject, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: 8KHYW3RCS2ZA7D95, HostID: kOLo+gY/dTzrROVswsB1bxinlN8w+XDL0LNMySUWJNHUPMBVk4ItdfP+mQ2xuo8ehaSnX/FaI4I=, api error AccessDenied: Access Denied`

Request body is something like this:

```
{
    "filekey": "https://xxx-xxx.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/agencies/photo/06%3A03%3A2023_17%3A42%3A42_gggi_db_er.png"
}
```

I got all these AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME, AWS_REGION, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY stored in .env file, plus I think I set them right since I got another route to upload file to S3 (which work just fine).

Comment: Did you check IAM policy for that user? Maybe you have PutObject, but not GetObject allowed? Or something similar.

Comment: Your `fileKey` is a URL, but not a valid S3 object key. When using GetObject or similar S3 APIs, it needs to be valid key such as `agencies/photo/xyz.png` and should not be URL-encoded.

Comment: look into presigned URL.  redirect to presigned url would be a lot more efficient than downloading s3 object and then sending the whole thing back out to user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fileKey is a URL like this:

```
"https://xxx-xxx.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/agencies/photo/06%3A03%3A2023_17%3A42%3A42_gggi_db_er.png"
```

That is only usable from an HTTP client such as a web browser or curl.

Specifically, it is not a valid S3 object key. When using GetObject or similar S3 APIs, it needs to be a valid key such as `agencies/photo/xyz.png` and should not be URL-encoded.

Comment: @Jackk, Keep in mind that the S3 web console will provide a public https link to objects regardless of whether the object is publicly accessible.

Comment: Thank you all for the answer. May I ask one more thing, is there any problem in this line about buffer reader `buf := make([]byte, 100)` ? Is this good for memory consumption ? I am so not clear about this buffer thing.

Comment: There is code for multi-part downloading large objects using the download manager in the last example at [Upload or download large files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/go_2_s3_code_examples.html).